# Getting error while creating NGinx Ingress rules, failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io"

Tags: azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have deployed `Nginx Ingress Controller` over `Azure AKS` and it's running well.

`helm upgrade --install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx-3.10.1.tgz -n ingress-nginx`

[image]

While I'm trying deploy below Ingress rule file, I am greeting below error,

[image]

Error is,

> Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post "https://nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded

What this error meaning and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an ingress rule to allow access on port `8443` on your AKS cluster nodes.

Look at the [Helm chart values](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml), you will see the port used here:

```
controller.admissionWebhooks.port
```